# Если условие выполнено, то открыть окно

Tags: javascript, html

Есть два input, если в оба инпута ввели данные допустим в первый input "123", а во второй input "123ABC", то условие выполнено. Если ввели неправильные значения цвет фона обоих input должны стать цвета #ee6369.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('check');

btn.onclick = function() {
  var ipn1 = document.getElementById('inp1'), // инпут 1
    ipn2 = document.getElementById('inp2'), // инпут 2
    val1 = inp1.value, // введенное value 1
    val2 = inp2.value; // введенное value 2
  if (val1 == '123' && val2 == '123ABC') { // если введено "123" и "123ABC"
    // ваш код
    inp1.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'; // перекрашиваем фон в белый
    inp2.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'; // перекрашиваем фон в белый
    console.log('Все верно');
  } else {
    inp1.style.backgroundColor = '#ee6369'; // перекрашиваем фон в красный
    inp2.style.backgroundColor = '#ee6369'; // перекрашиваем фон в красный
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="inp1" type="text" /><br />
<input id="inp2" type="text" /><br />
<button id="check">Проверить</button>
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!